# Python way of plotting a Tephigram and Hodograph

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, metpy

I am looking to plot a `Tephigram` using Python and so far I have noticed that there are no real ways of doing so and I do not have the meteorological training to start from a `SkewT` plot and customize it to a `Tephigram`. I am currently using [MetPy](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/Advanced_Sounding.html#sphx-glr-examples-advanced-sounding-py) to create plots like the one below but I do not think it is a valid `Tephigram`. I have looked at these [Issue 1](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/418),[Issue 2](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/613) and [Issue 3](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1731) as well as this [library](https://github.com/leifdenby/tephigram_python), but I am open to any library or method.

[image]

Comment: I suggest to post also on [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, there's no amount of customization you can do to a Skew-T to produce a Tephigram. Skew-T log-P diagrams plot pressure vs. temperature, with pressure on a logarithmic scale on the vertical, temperature rotated (nominally 45 degrees). Tephigrams fundamentally plot entropy (potential temperature) vs. temperature, with those two axes rotated 45 degrees.

The `tephigram_python` library you mentioned would have been what I linked you to, so I'm curious what its deficiencies are.